# Git error trying to retrieve log messages

Tags: git

I'm trying to lookup all commit messages between two commits, and I'm doing this with a call like:

```
git --no-pager log --pretty=oneline d875ae4b899411d70ec1d83f8f8d83430fd7d550...4b1d2046c070e82c23d4ced8f089d457f7c5b732
```

This has worked perfectly for months, but recently I started getting the error:

```
fatal: Invalid symmetric difference expression
```

with no further explanation. Google shows a few bug reports showing this error, but no resolutions. What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

This means that one or both of the two hashes you listed is for an object that does not exist.

Since each of `d875ae4b899411d70ec1d83f8f8d83430fd7d550` and `4b1d2046c070e82c23d4ced8f089d457f7c5b732` is a well formed hash ID, Git trusts that both are hash IDs.  Git looks in the object database for the two objects, so as to find their merge bases.  At least one object is not *in* the database, so Git complains.

Comment: You can check the commit ID currently checked out with the command `git rev-parse HEAD` and make sure it matches